# How to count how many times specific text exist in the DataTable?

Tags: c#, string, search, datatable, count

I have a DataTable with some columns. For example one of this columns contains the next values:

```
SOMEtext
SOMEnumber
SOMEnumber
SOMEnumber
SOMEtext
SOMEtext
SOMEnumber
SOMEtext
```

All of these values are strings

How can I count how many 'number' do I have in my table?

Comment: We need more information please give some example input and example expected output.

Comment: I got answer from Mitch. That's what i need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: A better method to use is [`Compute()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx):

```
int count = Convert.ToInt32(
               dataTable.Compute("Count(myColumnname)", "myColumnname Like '%number%'"));
```

<strike>You can use the [`DataTable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx) method:</strike>

```
DataRow[] rows = dataTable.Select("columnname Like '%number%'");

int count = rows.Length;
```